# How to produce a POM only containing dependency information?

Tags: java, maven

When publishing a library with Gradle, the resulting JAR will contain a minimum POM file which essentially just contains the dependency information required for *using* that library and some metadata such as license information.

Is there a way to achieve the same using Maven when building a JAR? I.e. I'm looking for a plug-in which gets rid of all the information from the project's POM which only is required for *building* the JAR such as used plug-ins, test-scoped dependencies etc.? All this information isn't needed for the consumers of the JAR, so I'd prefer to not publish it, reducing complexity for the users of my library.

Comment: You can take a look here: http://www.mojohaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly what I was looking for; thanks! Add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [flatten-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/) is intended to produce a pom file which contains only the information which is needed to consume the appropriate jar. It will remove the information like test scope dependencies profiles etc.